# How can I get the time in GMT using GWT?

Tags: gwt, timestamp, datetime-format, gmt

I want to get the current time of the machine in GMT and presented it on custom format like this one using GWT:

```
 yyyyMMddHHmmss
```

How I can achieve that?

I've tried this, but I didn't find how can I present this local time in GMT:

```
Date date = new Date();
DateTimeFormat dtf = DateTimeFormat.getFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
System.err.println(dtf.format(date).toString());
```

Also note that the `Date.getTimezoneOffset()` is deprecated, which I could use to subtract it from the current date and format it afterwards, but it doesn't sound like a good plan.

Comment: Isn't GWT using some unix standard or ISO standard?  What have you tried? You know about FormatDateTime... Try it.

Comment: @Warren P I updated my question.. but can you be more specific..?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
Date date = new Date();
DateTimeFormat dtf = DateTimeFormat.getFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
Window.alert(dtf.format(date, TimeZone.createTimeZone(0)));
```

You need to import `com.google.gwt.i18n.client.TimeZone` and not `java.util.TimeZone`.